# How could I re-write this code without the Calculator constructor?

Tags: javascript, calculator, class-constructors

I am making a calculator for a 12 week bootcamp and the MVP states we are not to use constructors.

Below is all the functions within the constructor. I need all of the functions to continue to work, I just need them NOT inside a constructor to meet the requirements of my MVP.

I understand conceptually how to make a calculator, and have opted to comb through and rewrite vanilla JS with notes throughout to solidify my understanding.

```
class Calculator {
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined
  }

  delete() {
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand === '') return
    if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
      this.compute()
    }
    this.operation = operation
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
    this.currentOperand = ''
  }

  compute() {
    let computation
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
    if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
    switch (this.operation) {
      case '+':
        computation = prev + current
        break
      case '-':
        computation = prev - current
        break
      case '*':
        computation = prev * current
        break
      case '÷':
        computation = prev / current
        break
      default:
        return
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation
    this.operation = undefined
    this.previousOperand = ''
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString()
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
    let integerDisplay
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = ''
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
    } else {
      return integerDisplay
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText =
      this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText =
        `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
    } else {
      this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a comment: the parameters to the constructor are useless, as the constructor assigns new values immediately by its call to `clear`.

Without prototype (class instance) functions, you could give every function a parameter that represents the state of the calculator. Or, if you would have used this class to create *one* instance only, you could make that state global, which is what may be the suggested approach in a beginner's course.

In the latter case (globals), define each current `this` property as global variable, like this:

```
var previousOperandTextElement = "", 
    currentOperandTextElement = "",
    operation;
```

And then:

- remove all occurrences of `this.` from the code
- insert the `function` keyword before every method
- move any code from the `constructor` just below the global `var` declarations
- remove the `class` wrapper and the `constructor` function

Like so:

```
var previousOperandTextElement = "", 
    currentOperandTextElement = "",
    operation;

clear();

function clear() {
    currentOperand = ''
    previousOperand = ''
    operation = undefined
}

function delete() {
    currentOperand = currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
}

function appendNumber(number) {
    if (number === '.' && currentOperand.includes('.')) return
    currentOperand = currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()
}

// ...etc ...etc
```

Comment: I'd add a warning to this answer regarding the globals approach being a horrible practice, no matter what their prof thinks. Passing the state around aka "c-style OOP" is much more solid.

Comment: Using classes/prototypes is much more solid too.