# JS Calculator - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, calculator, appendchild

EDIT 2: I'm just starting again from scratch. No point in trying to understand these complex problems problems right now when I am a novice. Have consulted someone from my cohort who can go through it with me. I appreciate the advice and insight.

I have been editing this code heavily, as the original relied a constructor. The calculator does not currently append any numbers to either displays when pushed, and I am not sure why! I think the problem lies somewhere in the appending/ node process or the update display function! Any and all advice/ ideas welcomed.

For context I am 5 weeks into a 12 week intensive course and am a baby baby baby coder. Please explain like I am 5!!!

EDIT: If you want to see original code please look at my previous question!

JAVA SCRIPT

```
const calculator =
  (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, operation);

clear = () => {
  currentOperand = "";
  previousOperand = "";
  operation = undefined;
};

remove = () => {
  currentOperand = currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1);
};


chooseOperation = (operation) => {
  if (currentOperand === "") return;
  if (previousOperand !== "") {
    compute();
  }

  operation = operation;
  previousOperand = currentOperand;
  currentOperand = "";
};

compute = () => {
  let computation;
  const prev = parseFloat(previousOperand);
  const current = parseFloat(currentOperand);
  if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return;
  switch (operation) {
    case "+":
      computation = prev + current;
      break;
    case "-":
      computation = prev - current;
      break;
    case "*":
      computation = prev * current;
      break;
    case "÷":
      computation = prev / current;
      break;
    default:
      return;
  }
  currentOperand = computation;
  operation = undefined;
  previousOperand = "";
};

getDisplayNumber = (number) => {
  const stringNumber = number.toString();
  const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split(".")[0]);
  const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split(".")[1];
  let integerDisplay;
  if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
    integerDisplay = "";
  } else {
    integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString("en", {
      maximumFractionDigits: 0,
    });
  }
  if (decimalDigits != null) {
    return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`;
  } else {
    return integerDisplay;
  }
};

updateDisplay = () => {
  currentOperandTextElement.innerText = getDisplayNumber(currentOperand);
  if (operation != null) {
    previousOperandTextElement.innerText = `${getDisplayNumber(
      previousOperand
    )} ${operation}`;
  } else {
    previousOperandTextElement.innerText = "";
  }
};

appendNumber = (number) => {
  if (number === "." && currentOperand.includes(".")) return;
  currentOperand = currentOperand.toString() + number.toString();
};


equalsButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.compute();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

numberButtons.forEach = (button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
};

operationButtons.forEach = (button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
};

allClearButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.clear();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", (button) => {
  calculator.delete();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});

item = (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) => {
  previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement;
  currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement;
  clear();
};

const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("[data-equals]");
const deleteButton = document.querySelector("[data-delete]");
const allClearButton = document.querySelector("[data-all-clear]");

const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(
  "[data-previous-operand]"
);
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector(
  "[data-current-operand]"
);
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <script src="calcedit.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="calculator-grid">
      <div class="output">
        <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand"></div>
        <div data-current-operand class="current-operand"></div>
      </div>
      <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
      <button data-delete>DEL</button>
      <button data-operation>÷</button>
      <button data-number>1</button>
      <button data-number>2</button>
      <button data-number>3</button>
      <button data-operation>x</button>
      <button data-number>4</button>
      <button data-number>5</button>
      <button data-number>6</button>
      <button data-operation>+</button>
      <button data-number>7</button>
      <button data-number>8</button>
      <button data-number>9</button>
      <button data-operation>-</button>
      <button data-number>.</button>
      <button data-number>0</button>
      <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your HTML too.

Comment: This is not how you create an object: `const calculator =
  (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, operation);`

Comment: I notice that you have zero logging in your code. Unless you know which paths are being executed (if so, share them) then you should add logging (e.g. `console.log("In deleteButton handler")`) so you can trace what is actually executing.

Comment: Put you code in a https://jsfiddle.net/.  That way we can play around with the code

Comment: @Aaron We prefer Stack Snippets now.

Comment: Hey everyone, here is JS Fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/n69vh3qo/#&togetherjs=o9UCU4l6Tt (sorry Barmar)

Answer (score 1):

So reading through your code, this issue is related to your understanding of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401243/how-could-i-re-write-this-code-without-the-calculator-constructor)

removing the Class means you no longer have a `calculator` instance or Object to work with so you can to work in a more procedural way

To start with

```
const calculator =
  (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement, operation);
```

Should be replaced with

```
var previousOperandTextElement = "", 
    currentOperandTextElement = "",
    operation;
```

Anywhere you've got `calculator` for example `calculator.compute();` should just be replaced with the new function you've created, in this case `compute();` because you don't have a `calculator` object to work with.

As the previous comments suggested, for this may not be a good approach and a class / prototype approach might be better (what you had originally)